# Saving app data, or recovering the data once the app has been deleted

Tags: ios

I have an Ipad air 1, which currently has an app that won't start. I have information on the app, that won't start, but if I delete the app I will lose the data. Is there any way I can back up the app's data, or save it before deleting the app and restoring the data?

**Ipad specs:**

```
Model: md792b/a 
ios version is 10.3 ios
```

I have looked at phonedisk, which seems to only be valid up to 10.10, any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is simply not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Look a view May be it will be helpfull http://addpod.com/juicephone.
this one too https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15183/can-i-extract-application-data-from-an-ios-device